# How can I optimise and improve this circuit for audio applications?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, amplifier

I am designing a basic preamp using the LM741 opamp to amplifier frequencies from 20 to 20KHZ to a 10Kohm load, input voltage is 0.5V and I get an output voltage of around 2V, what else can I do to reduce noise and distortion? 
[image: opamp]

Comment: Step 1: throw out that decrepit old 741 and use an opamp from this century.

Comment: Okay, can you suggest a replacement?

Comment: Why are you loading down the input to 100 ohms? What's your source impedance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sine wave, there is no DC element. So using C1 polarity cap will distort the signal, you can use non-polarity aluminum cap.

C1 R3 is a high pass filter, 100 ohm is too low too drive properly for line output. Recommend value is 10uF and 10k ohm, the roll off frequency is 2Hz and below.

Increase R1 + R2 resistance to above 10k ohm, opamp would drive better.

The circuit gain is 5, you would get 2.5V instead of 2V.

Use a low noise opamp like MC33078.

Add a low pass filter by adding a small cap across R1.

Comment: What value should I choose for the cap across R1, is 0.1uF okay?

Comment: Here are some design ideas. http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_5.html

Comment: Thank you, I think I might use the NE5534 instead of the MC33078.

Answer (score -1):

1. A ua741 is just fine for this.
2. Check the data sheet for minimal gain required. If have to atteuate on the output.
3. Get your gain right
4. Use a reasonable R3. And C1 for your application.
5. Size up the rails for adequate swing. Check the data sheet for minimum headroom lost.

...

Comment: It looks like there should be something between every row in this answer.